# XPath: Getting an element where one of its childs has certain conditions

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<database name="acgg_onfarm">
        <table_data name="birdentext_maintable">
        <row>
                <field name="surveyid">95419b4f-006f-44c4-b83d-bc6e0ef18478</field>
                <field name="originid">FORMHUB-JSON</field>
                <field name="meta_devid">865770027212853</field>
                <field name="start_time">2017-07-26 14:31:07</field>
                <field name="survey_date">2017-07-14 00:00:00</field>
                <field name="date_yyyymmdd">20170714</field>
                <field name="subscriber_id" xsi:nil="true" />
                <field name="phone_number">0947428980</field>
                <field name="end_time">2017-07-26 14:32:31</field>
                <field name="onfarm_country">E</field>
                <field name="onfarm_subnatarea">AA</field>
                <field name="onfarm_village">198</field>
                <field name="onfarm_enum">198</field>
                <field name="householdid">EAA2001</field>
                <field name="householdid_key">EAA2001_20170714</field>
                <field name="bent_general">0</field>
                <field name="bext_general">1</field>
                <field name="rowuuid">7fbf04b1-7fd6-4920-9a1f-8d375020af1b</field>
        </row>
        <row>
                <field name="surveyid">e5d2810e-2db4-40ef-baf0-15c77d31797a</field>
                <field name="originid">FORMHUB-JSON</field>
                <field name="meta_devid">865770027212853</field>
                <field name="start_time">2017-08-14 05:13:49</field>
                <field name="survey_date">2017-08-14 00:00:00</field>
                <field name="date_yyyymmdd">20170814</field>
                <field name="subscriber_id" xsi:nil="true" />
                <field name="phone_number">0947428980</field>
                <field name="end_time">2017-08-14 05:15:08</field>
                <field name="onfarm_country">E</field>
                <field name="onfarm_subnatarea">AA</field>
                <field name="onfarm_village">198</field>
                <field name="onfarm_enum">198</field>
                <field name="householdid">EAA2001</field>
                <field name="householdid_key">EAA2001_20170814</field>
                <field name="bent_general">0</field>
                <field name="bext_general">1</field>
                <field name="rowuuid">1070fb2c-58b2-4155-84a8-ec40ef669919</field>
        </row>
    </table_data>
</database>
```

Im trying to get the row and its childs elements where it contains a field with attribute "name" = rowuuid and its value is b93c6113-7508-42aa-8549-267f0956b935

I'm a bit stuck here: I tried:

```
//field[@name='rowuuid' and . = 'b93c6113-7508-42aa-8549-267f0956b935']
```

But this only return the field...

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Isn't it something like `//row[./field[@name='rowuuid' and . = 'b93c6113-7508-42aa-8549-267f0956b935']]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//row[field[@name='rowuuid' and .='b93c6113-7508-42aa-8549-267f0956b935']]
```

will return all `row` elements with a child `field` element named `rowuuid` that has string value of `b93c6113-7508-42aa-8549-267f0956b935`.